# Spring + JAX.RS - context loaded twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jersey

I am developing application that serves REST API for clients, to do this I decided to use `JAX-RS` implementation `Jersey` and `Spring` for some dependency injection.

Today I noticed in my logs, that my application context seems to be loaded twice, for example:

```
2013-12-21 22:18:55 INFO  ContextLoader:272 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2013-12-21 22:18:55 INFO  ContextLoader:272 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
```

I looked through similiar posts, but seeing my `web.xml` file, I can't seem to  find the culprit:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestPowtorkiServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>org.powtorki.spring.PowtorkiApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestPowtorkiServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!--
    Apply Spring Security Filter to all REST Requests
 -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Also I tried running example app from `Jersey` repository (https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.4.1/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp) and it seems it is suffering from the same issue.

Is it a bug in `Spring` integration with `Jersey`? If so is there a way to fix it somehow?

EDIT:
log4j configuration:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.category.org.springframework.data.document.mongodb=DEBUG,stdout
log4j.logger.org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader=DEBUG,stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Please post your logger configuration.

Comment: Added it in the original post edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a log4j `Appender` property known as **additivity**. It is described as

> The output of a log statement of logger C will go to all the appenders
>   in C and its ancestors. This is the meaning of the term "appender
>   additivity".
>
> However, if an ancestor of logger C, say P, has the additivity flag
>   set to false, then C's output will be directed to all the appenders in
>   C and its ancestors upto and including P but not the appenders in any
>   of the ancestors of P.

Therefore your statements logged on `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader` will also go to `rootLogger` which is its parent.

You can set its additivity flag to `false` by putting

```
log4j.additivity.org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader=false
```